# What is the reason behind Android showing multiple dialogs when tapped fast?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

can someone explain why Android shows multiple dialogs when tapped fast?

Comment: because you may be creating new dialog in every tap. And no one can answer properly just seeing your question. It is totally unclear.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's because when you create a new dialog it doesn't get focus until it has finished the animation where it pops up, so you can still receive taps in the activity that created it, which means you can create multiple dialogs if you are creating them in onClick events. It's powerfully annoying, but you can work around it by keeping track of whether a dialog is already opening.

Answer (score 2):

When You call new YourClassDialog() , the chain of request/tap event  would cause new Dialog to be  generated and Each is saved into Memory. So It will show.